# when does process migrate from suspended waiting to suspended ready in operating system

Tags: process, operating-system

when does a process migrate from **suspended wait** to **wait**
and when does a process migrate from **suspended wait** to **suspended ready**?

process gets suspended frm waiting state if a higher priority process requires i/o and all i/o is already filled
so if an i/o becomes free process should move back to waiting state frm suspended wait right?

Comment: Your use of wait/ready may be a little mixed up here. I/O is related to blocking and suspension is related to memory management. The wikipedia page for [Process State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_state) covers the topic well. It may help you ask the question better if it doesn't resolve it outright.